# Dynamically configured virtual hosting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dynamic, virtualhost

Helo!
I would like to prepare a dynamic virtual host for all subdomains that will be created in future using mod_rewrite. All subdomains would be configured prety much same way, so i thought of using dynamic VH configuration.
I want my document root for each subdomain to be /home/user/public_html/subdomainName.

I've tried with following configuration, but had no success:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    # get the server name from the Host: header
    UseCanonicalName Off

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/>
    # ExecCGI is needed here because we can't force
    # CGI execution in the way that ScriptAlias does
      Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On

    # a ServerName derived from a Host: header may be any case at all
    RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

    #rule that is suposed to set document root of virtual host!??? 
    RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)\.domain\.com/?(.*) /home/user/public_html/$1/$2

</VirtualHost>
```

The rule or somethinh seems to be wrong andit doesn't apply. I've never worked with dynamic VH before so i have no idea where i'm wrong...

Comment: This question is more appropriate for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

This is a need a lot of people had before you. So there's an apache module which can do that for you **mod_vhost_alias**  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html

> Provides for dynamically configured
>   mass virtual hosting

Answer (score 0):

instead of dynamic virtual hosts, you can also do this using wildcard dns which means configuring {anything}.yourdomain.tld to point to your server.

This will also get you same document root for each domain.

note that you will need to add `ServerAlias *.yourdomain.tld` to the virtual host entry

Comment: Tnx, but if possible i would like to have separate documentRoot for each subdomain. Otherwise my aplication in subdomains doesn't work correctly (wrong paths).

Answer (score 0):

With RewriteRule you can't access the domainname. Also use RewriteCond for that part and use %1 etc. for backreference.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1
```

The only problem is this will create a continues loop of prepending the subdomainname string. So what I normally do is create a separate folder for subdomains, like 'subdomains'

```
RewriteRule ^subdomains - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z-]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) subdomains/%1/$1
```

Comment: Tnx! I've tried this before but got caught in the loop that I've now solved by your subdomains folder idea. Now i wonder if it's also posible to change DocumentRoot for each subdomain so it would point directly to the folder /subdomains/subdomainName ?? Is this posible with a rewrite VH solution or would i have to make separate VirtualHost for each subdomain?

Comment: The documentRoot is fixed per VH. So either your work around the 'incorrectness' of the DocumentRoot value, or you have to create a VH for every subdomain. What do you need DocumentRoot for?

Comment: Each subdomain is suposed to contain an instance of my CRM application. But when i was programming it i thought it would be on root, so i used php's $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], ... Now those paths are incorect, because app. is placed two levels under documentRoot. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You could add an auto prepend php file that modifies the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] variable based on the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. I'm not sure if you can directly change $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] from apache/htaccess

Comment: I'm probably just gona correct the paths to relative, so documentRoot won't matter... Tnx anyway!